# r data.table excluding rows with certain value in a column removes NAs too

Tags: r, data.table, operators, logical-operators

I came accross this unexpected behaviour in `data.table`. Rows with `NAs` in a certain column are removed when excluding rows with a certain value as in this example:

```r
library(data.table)

dt_mtcars <- setDT(copy(mtcars))

set.seed(42)
na_rows <- runif(3, min = 1, max = nrow(mtcars))

dt_mtcars[ na_rows, cyl := NA]

dt_mtcars[ is.na(cyl), .N]
#> [1] 3

dt_mtcars <- dt_mtcars[ cyl != 4]

dt_mtcars[ is.na(cyl), .N]
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Excluding rows instead like

```r
library(data.table)

dt_mtcars <- setDT(copy(mtcars))

set.seed(42)
na_rows <- runif(3, min = 1, max = nrow(mtcars))

dt_mtcars[ na_rows, cyl := NA]

dt_mtcars[ is.na(cyl), .N]
#> [1] 3

dt_mtcars <- dt_mtcars[ !cyl %in% 4]

dt_mtcars[ is.na(cyl), .N]
#> [1] 3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

does have the expected result. Am I wrong in expecting this same result in the first example above? Or is this a bug in `data.table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a `data.table` issue.

In the first case you don't select `NA`s:

```
NA != 4
[1] NA
```

In the second case you do:

```
!NA %in% 4
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I find this really surprising behaviour. It appears that `NA` cannot be interpreted as logical by R. EDIT: You're right in saying that it is not a `data.table`-specific issue. I tested this with a dataframe and got the same result.

Comment: @o_v, to interpret `NA` as logical, you'll need `is.na`. This behaviour is similar to  `SQL` where `NULL = NULL` isn't `TRUE`